# Finding $n$ if the given number is perfect square

Tags: number-theory

Find $n$, if $2^{200}-2^{192} \cdot 31+2^n$ is a perfect square.

$$2^{200}-2^{192} \cdot 31+2^n = 2^{192}(2^8-31)+2^n = 2^{192}(256-31)+2^n = 2^{192}  \cdot 225+2^n$$

For some $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $$2^n = m^2-2^{192} \cdot 225 = (m-2^{96} \cdot 15)(m+2^{96} \cdot 15)$$

Please guide further how to get the result.

Comment: Does this apply: there is a Pythagorean triplet (8,15,17)

Comment: Hint: Consider the exponent of 2 in the prime factorization of $m$

Answer (score 6):

\begin{align}
2^n & = m^2 - 2^{192}(2^8-31) = m^2 -225\cdot 2^{192}\\
& = m^2 - (15 \cdot 2^{96})^2 = (m+15 \cdot 2^{96})(m-15 \cdot 2^{96})
\end{align}
Hence,
$$m+15 \cdot 2^{96} = 2^k$$ 
$$m-15 \cdot 2^{96} = 2^{n-k}$$
Hence,
$$30 \cdot 2^{96} = 2^k - 2^{n-k} \implies 2^{97} \cdot 3 \cdot 5 = 2^{n-k} \cdot (2^{2k-n} - 1)$$
Hence,
$$n-k = 97$$
$$2k-n = 4$$This gives us $k=101$ and $n = 198$.

**EDIT**

Note that $$2^{200}-31 \cdot 2^{192} + 2^{198} = 2^{192} \cdot (2^8 - 31 + 2^6) = 2^{192} \cdot (256 - 31 + 64) = 2^{192} \cdot 289 = (2^{96} \cdot 17)^2$$